# Can't add value to an empty data table

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I created an empty data table `dt` with columns `id`, `begin`, and `end`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=numeric(), begin=numeric(),end=numeric())
```

I tried to add value 1 to the first row of column `id`.

```
dt$id[1] <- 1
```

But its value is still `NA`. I don't know what's wrong.

```
dt$id[1]
# [1] NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use `rbind()`.  This defaults to `rbindlist()`, which allows us to use `fill = TRUE`.  It has the advantage of simplicity in cases where we want to add many values for only one variable.

```
rbind(dt, list(id = 1), fill = TRUE)
#    id begin end
# 1:  1    NA  NA

rbind(dt, list(id = 1:4), fill = TRUE)
#    id begin end
# 1:  1    NA  NA
# 2:  2    NA  NA
# 3:  3    NA  NA
# 4:  4    NA  NA
```

**Option 2:** Create a row of `NA` with `dt[1]` then assign 1 to `id`.  Problem here is that we have to name the other columns as well.  This is likely not useful if we have many columns.

```
dt[1, .(id = 1, begin, end)]
#    id begin end
# 1:  1    NA  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `rbind(dt, list(1, NA, NA))`